# User control vs Control Template in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, controltemplate

I have recently reviewing someone's code and come across a User Control whose UI is like this screenshot

[image]

This control has no code in its code behind file, i am thinking we could move all the xaml code of this user control to a control template and use it whereever required. I want to know if this a good practice and should i do so?

Is their any performance and design benefit of one approach over another?

Comment: if it is a user control and let it be user control why do you think using control template is necessary?

Comment: Getting the XAML and making it a control template is fine. I don't know about the performance hit. Be sure the usercontol will not be used anywhere in the background..

Comment: @Saurabh I don't think it is necessary, i just can't think about any benefit except adding couples of files in the solution. Please let me know if it had some benefits over control templates which i could define in my resource dictionary.

Comment: @JordyvanEijk I dont understand the part usercontrol will not be used anywhere in the background, did you mean using user control at runtime(from cs).

Comment: Generally, you could verify if the visual tree and the logical tree are the same in the case you're doing the control template way. I remembered they're different when logical tree is taken into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know if this a good practice

So first we should define good practice? I will give the agile good practice point of view: do it only if you need it. Thus for you the answer is in your question:

> use it whereever required

Is it required in any other place? If so, use a Control Template. If not, use a User Control, which will be more readable for the next developper anyway (Keep It Stupid and Simple).

Comment: I don't understand the second part of the answer. A user control is just as reusable as a Control Template; Are you suggesting that the User Control should be transformed into a Control Template if it's used in more then one place? Wny?

Comment: I just suggest that it depends of your context. I find User Control more readable, so I would use Control Template only if I have to for different reason (maybe architecture or legacy  constraints). But as MegaMind seems to prefer Control Template in its context, I just say: at least use it only if it is required in another place.

Answer (score 1):

Since ultimately this is going to be a UserCotrol,Now suppose some other team working on other module require this control and they want Loaded event of the Datagrid within this Control, Now if you create it as datagrid within usercontrol then they can easily access that datagrid and subscribe Load Event to it. If you will do it in ControlTemplate then it will be difficult if not impossible.